# QGraphics Scene Zooming in and out

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

Here I am again worrying about how to Zoom in and out a QGraphicsPixmapItem in a graphics scene. I looked for a direct method for this but could not find any in graphics scene or in pix map. Can someone help me with this. Do I have to extend QGraphicsPixmapItem and implement methods for this.

Thanks again for help and I really do appreciate it.

~Tharanga

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Did not know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsPixmapItem` inherits from `QGraphicsItem`, so it has all of that class's methods.

In particular, there's [`setScale`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale) that will change the item's scale factor (i.e. "zoom" it).

Look at the [Transformations Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/painting-transformations.html) page for how this is done, and other transformations you can do.

Answer (score 2):

setScale() changes the size of the item, not the view scale of the scene. For a one item scene, it's effectively the same. But if you have more than one item in the scene, it changes the relation between items.

[`QGraphicsView::setTransform()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#setTransform) should be used if you want to keep the item's relationship to the scene and other items.